# Aspnetcore 2.2 Targeting .Net Framework, InProcess fails on azure app service with error TTP Error 500.0 - ANCM In-Process Handler Load Failure

Tags: c#, azure, iis, asp.net-core

I did upgrade of my app to aspnetcore 2.2 but due to some legacy limitations which I am planing to remove later I must target .NET Framework.

New hosting model InProcess bring improvements so I want to use it but when I deploy to azure I am getting error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <!--AspNetCoreModuleV2 switch back when its released on azure-->
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\Flymark.Online.Web.exe" arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile="../stdout" hostingModel="InProcess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

And my error

> HTTP Error 500.0 - ANCM In-Process Handler Load Failure Common causes
>   of this issue: The specified version of Microsoft.NetCore.App or
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.App was not found. The in process request
>   handler, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS, was not referenced in the
>   application. ANCM could not find dotnet. Troubleshooting steps: Check
>   the system event log for error messages Enable logging the application
>   process' stdout messages Attach a debugger to the application process
>   and inspect For more information visit:
>   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=2028526

If I change same app to be outofprocess and module to v1 it works as expected

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <!--AspNetCoreModuleV2 switch back when its released on azure-->
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\Flymark.Online.Web.exe" arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile="../stdout" hostingModel="OutOfProcess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

I am publishing my app using Azure pipelines and MSbuild.

Comment: Changing  modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" to  modules="AspNetCoreModule" worked for me too. (Not saying that is the correct thing to do!) But it worked for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of today it seems In-Process is not supported when targeting .Net Framework. [Issue on github](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/6482)

Comment: @KinjalParmar I am using out of process. There is no and will be no solution rather than that.

Comment: Thanks for sharing @volodymyr-bilyachat Can you please send any document link of how to do out of process? Thanks.

Comment: @KinjalParmar https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Tysm @volodymyr

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I get the shared web.config from my colleague and the build path is not correct for me. Correct the path then it works!

[image]

Comment: Your case is a bit differnt you are not using InProcess hosting model

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat I missed that part in the captured image. I confirmed that Im using the hostingModel = "InProcess"

Comment: Yes but again you compile your project as netcore while mine was .Net Framework :)